# Calling DFP ad with custom params via the SDK

Tags: android, google-dfp, google-ad-exchange

I am displaying dfp ad inside my mobile android app

The id of the dfp ad looks like this:

> /1234567/game_intertitial

Say i want to set custom params like this:

> /1234567/game_intertitial?cust_params=bid=5‏

Is it possible to do in the mobile android sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to use to use the sdk for this like this:

```
final PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
            .addCustomTargeting(key, val)
            .build();
```